# Convert ISO 8601 Date-string to .NET DateTime

Tags: datetime

convert this string `2012-10-31T09:05:25+0000`  to .NET DateTime
 I am getting this string from facebook json

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-31T09:05:25+0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)**.
It is an **[ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)** date-string.

```
inputStr = "2012-10-31T09:05:25+0000";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputStr, "u", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```